# in c#, math is correct, output is wrong. calculating sum of reciprocals

Tags: c#, math

http://imageshack.com/a/img923/5162/R6tZQr.jpg

is the outcome the is supposed to occur. here is my code

```
static void CalcN()
{
  Console.Write(" ");
  for (uint n = 1; n <= 9; n++)
  {
    p = (n*n*(sides-2) - n*(sides-4)) / 2;
    Console.Write("{0,3} ", p);
    sumOfRecip += (1/p);
  }
  Console.WriteLine("{0}",sumOfRecip);
}
```

and my output showing the calculations for "n" are correct, but when trying to add sum of reciprocals, it is wrong. and I can't get Math.Round to work with the calculating reciprocals.

```
    Sum of
n=9 recip
--- ------
 45 1.8000
 81 3.3398
117 4.7504
153 6.0827
189 7.3620
225 8.6031
261 9.8152
297 11.0046
333 12.1756
369 13.3316
405 14.4750
```

Comment: you should show all the source, including where the value of sides and sumOfRecip is initialized.  Also, are you doing integer math with division there?

Comment: Can you point to where it is wrong?  That way readers don't have to check each value.

Comment: you probably need to reset your sumOfRecip so it just doesnt keep getting added to.

Comment: I did need to reset it to 0 after the loop. I knew it was an easy fix. I had a 4 hour long problem with Math.Pow(n,2) making the triangular section in the negatives.... never quite figured that one out. Swapped to n*n and worked like a charm.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't being bitten by integer division?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to reset your `sumOfRecip` so it just doesnt keep getting added to.

```
3.3398 - 1.8 = the value you want.
```

You should make `sumOfRecip` a local variable inside `CalcN()` unless you really need it outside that function.  Make variables as local as they can be.

Comment: only problem now is `Math.Round(sumOfRecip += (1/p),4);` isn't rounding it to 4 decimal points

Comment: what's it doing if not rounding?

Comment: its writing the sums with too many decimal points. `1.53976773116654` i'd post a block code if i knew how in the comments to show you more code

Comment: if you could show the code where you're doing this it would be helpful.  You might want to use Decimal instead of double or other float types.  double/float sometimes have a hard time storing precisely enough.  you can use http://pastebin.com/ and post a link.  should probably take this to a chat room, comments arent meant for this kind of chatter.

Comment: possible to add me on skype john?

Comment: add me via email on it >jonbutler10198@gmail.com